# tf.image.non_max_suppression gives Uninitialized tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, non-maximum-suppression

I'm using tensorflow's `tf.image.non_max_suppression` in Faster-RCNN network. The tensorflow graph builds successfully and also runs without errors, but when running the graph, the output is empty tensors, with the dimension that depends on the input having size 0 (e.g., I get output tensors of shape (0,4)). So I used `tfdbg` tool to see what's going on. I found that the tensor value is `Uninitialized tensor` for the `tf.image.non_max_suppression` op. All subsequent tensors depending on the output of the nms op also show as `Unintialized tensor`.

I had trained this Faster-RCNN network and saved the weights using `tf.train.Saver(..).save(..)`. When I trained the network, I was using a python numpy function to do NMS and it was plugged into the network using the op wrapper `tf.py_func`, then after the model was trained, I decided to changed the python function to a tensorflow implementation.

`tf.image.non_max_suppression` has no learnable parameters so I don't understand why when I now load the saved model and run the graph, the tensor is uninitialized. I also tried to do `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` before loading the model with `tf.train.Saver(..).restore(..)` but there's no change, still seeing `Uninitialized tensor` in `tfdbg` for the NMS and subsequent ops.

Any ideas about this behaviour and how it can be solved ?

This is how I use `tf.image.non_max_suppression` :

> ```
> keep = tf.image.non_max_suppression(proposals_yxyx, 
>                              scores, 
>                              tf.constant(cfg[cfg_key].RPN_POST_NMS_TOP_N), 
>                              cfg[cfg_key].RPN_NMS_THRESH, 
>                              name="Non-maximal-suppression")
> ```

Comment: Can you include the full error message, including any tensor names?

Comment: I get no errors during building or running. Just get empty tensors when running, where the first dimension (which has size dependent on input) has size 0. When I debug using `tfdbg` I see that the nms op is `Uninitialized tensor`, as well as all subsequent tensors depending on the output of the nms op @mrry